# Proxy gateway send HTTP response back

Tags: go, proxy

I am looking to make a proxy gateway in Go.
Almost done ! One thing is still missing : send the entire client response to the server request.

I've got my own HTTP handler :

```
func (f HttpHandlerFunc) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if rurl, err := getOriginurl(r.RequestURI); err == nil {
        [...]
        client := &Http.Client{}
        r.URL = rurl
        r.RequestURI = ""
        resp, err := client.Do(r)
        if err == nil {
            for k, vs := range resp.Header {
                for _, v := range vs {
                    w.Header().Set(k, v)
                }
            }
            w.WriteHeader(resp.StatusCode)
            if responseData,err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body); err == nil {
                w.Write(responseData)
            }
        }
    }
}

func getOriginurl(request string) *url.URL {
   {...}
   // Would return an *url.URL with : http://127.0.0.1:8080/{requestURI}
}
```

I am looking for a way to optimize the way to parse Client response to ResponseWriter.
Actually my question would be  : **How to parse Response type to ResponseWriter exhaustively ?**

Comment: i think it's fine. As far as parsing a single response goes, you needn't optimize anymore. Looking at the interface that is http.ResponseWriter i also believe you are exhaustive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httputil@go1.13.8?tab=doc#NewSingleHostReverseProxy) instead of your own HTTP client logic.

```
httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(rurl).ServeHTTP(w, r)
```

Comment: You true. But I still need to do something with the requests. I'll look further at the serverHTTP function  [httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy.ServeHTTP](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.13.8/src/net/http/httputil/reverseproxy.go#L177) and be exhaustive with it :) Thx !

Comment: What do you want to do with the requests? Modify some headers?

Comment: I use the ServeHTTP as parent call of my handler and it's work perfectly ! :D For now I just wan't to log requests for further experimentation ^^